# Feedforward Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

Will there ever come a point in my epoch where my weights would become greater than 1 if i used the logistic function as my sigmoid? Just wanna check if i'm coding the proper way for my   feedforward implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible. E.g. If you have a 1-input, 1-output feedforward network that has no bias, your only training input is 0.1 and the corresponding output is 1, then the higher the weight, the better. The logistic function simply ensures that the output is between 0 and 1.

Comment: How about if the error for my training dataset increases, is that also possible?